# How to set gradient color for image view in Android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I already know how to adjust the color of the icon in the Image with code like this

```
val colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(this@MainActivity, R.color.colorWhite), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP)
    ivImage.colorFilter = colorFilter
```

I want to ask, is there a way to set that gradient color for the ImageView icon?

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can use xml file to set gradient!

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient android:startColor="@color/transcendence"
        android:endColor="@color/passion"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I think this is the color set for the background, but I need to set it for the ImageView icon

Answer (score -1):

You can apply a gradient color to an ImageView icon by code in Android. You'll need to create a GradientDrawable and then set it as the background of the ImageView. Here's an example:

```
val colors = intArrayOf(Color.RED, Color.BLUE) // Your gradient colors
val gradientDrawable = GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors)
gradientDrawable.shape = GradientDrawable.OVAL // Set the shape as per your requirement
ivImage.background = gradientDrawable
```

This code creates a gradient drawable with red and blue colors, sets orientation to top-bottom, and then sets it as the background of the ImageView *ivImage*. Adjust the colors and orientation as needed for your gradient effect.

Comment: I think this is the color set for the background, but I need to set it for the ImageView icon